# VB.Net Make Inherited Overridable Method take different parameter

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have a situation in VB.Net where I have a variable that will be an instance of one of two classes, both derived from a parent class, but which class is determined at run time. To do this, I declare the variable as the parent class, then set it to one or the other child class based on a true/false value.

After that, I invoke the only public method (Main) for the child class, I want the parameter it takes be different based on which child class it is. However, I'm finding that I can't do this with an override or overload, at least as I understand them. Is there a way to do this?

I guess I could have Main1 and Main2 as inherited methods with the specific parameter type and invoke them conditionally as well, but just looking to see if I can keep it simple.

Here's a mock-up of what I'm trying to accomplish, which doesn't work:

```
Public Class ThisParam
End Class

Public Class Param1
    Inherits ThisParam
End Class

Public Class Param2
    Inherits ThisParam
End Class

Public Class ThisBase
    Public Overridable Sub Main (X as ThisParam)
        'Empty for inheritance
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Child1
    Inherits ThisBase

    Public Overrides Sub Main(X as Param1)
       'Do Stuff
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Child2
    Inherits ThisBase

    Public Overrides Sub Main(X as Param2)
       'Do Stuff
    End Sub
End Class

Dim MyObject As ThisBase
Dim MyParam as ThisParam

If True then MyObject = New Child1 Else MyObject = New Child2 End If
If True then MyParam =  New Param1 Else MyParam = New Param2 End If

MyObject.Main(MyParam)
```

Comment: You need an overload.

Comment: I did try an overload, but because the initial declaration of MyParam is ThisParam (base class) and not Param1 or Param2, that's the parameter type the compliler is expecting in the last line of my example. I still couldn't get it to take Param1 or Param2 as an argument.

Comment: ...or a generic possibly.  if `ChildClass` was `ChildClass(Of T)` where T is `Param1` or `Param2`, you could dispense with one or more of the classes there.  The question is pretty abstract to be certain what you are after.

Comment: A method with different arguments does *not* override a base method.  It can't, no way to call it through a reference to the base class.  You need to consider this a bug in your design.